# Can Jack ever take a hit without getting stunned?

Tags: mary-skelter-nightmares

The more I use Jack, the more useless he seems (as a defender). One of the things he is able to do in battle is act as a human shield for one of the other party members, however, every single time I've done this and the person he was defending was attacked, he became Stunned and was unable to act for roughly 3 turns. After realizing that Jack was the only one in the party who can *use items*, it didn't make much sense anymore to use him to Defend if he was going to be Stunned every single time he took a hit.

Is Jack eventually able to take more than a single hit before becoming Stunned? Is there always a chance that he *doesn't* become Stunned and I've just been incredibly unlucky? Or is Jack fated to become Stunned whenever he takes a hit?

Comment: Obviously when fighting lower leveled enemies, he would be able to survive a hit or two. But I've been able to survive in the third area as well but I was at level 28 or so. So, sure he can.

Comment: @JeffMercado that's pretty much an answer... if you could find out for sure if it's level-based or if there's a bit of luck involved, etc, that would be super helpful.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I have no idea. I'm just grinding for levels and CP and have on occasion noticed he doesn't got knocked out instantly.

Comment: @JeffMercado wait knocked out or Stunned? I know it's possible that he can be knocked out for an entire battle, but I'm talking about Stun, where he has to take 2-3 turns to recover and be usable again (e.g. use the Mary Gun or any items)

Comment: Sorry, I mean stun. It's all the same for me. When he's stunned, he's out for pretty much rest of the fight as fights are relatively quick.